# INC malfunction in inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, x86, x86-64, inline-assembly

In this code:

```
int a[2]={5,2},i=0;
asm volatile
(
"incl %1\n"
"incl %0"
:"+r"(a[i]),"+r"(i)
:
:
);
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
```

I'm trying to increase `a[1]` by `1` (for a result of 2+1=`3`) but the output shows `2`, which means it hasn't changed. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Both inputs are read (into registers like the constraints require) before the increment happens.  So you've done `a[i++]++`, and then printing `a[i]` is the element you didn't modify.

Comment: `a[i]` gets evaluated before the asm code, so the order of operations is basically: 1) `i++`, 2) `a[0]++`.

Comment: And BTW, there's no syntax to require gcc to use `%1` as part of an addressing mode for a `"+m"` operand.  Especially not with a scaled-index addressing mode so +1 would offset by 4 bytes.  If you want to write stuff in asm, write whole functions in asm.  It's much easier to write ABI-compliant functions than to get the constraints right for a small snippet of asm.

Comment: Not that you'd want to do this in line assembly under normal circumstances but this migth have been closer to what you wanted: `asm
    ("incl %0\n\t"
     "incl (%1, %q0, 4)"
     :"+&r"(i)
     :"r"(a)
     :"memory"
);`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: `%q0` isn't guaranteed to be safe: there could be garbage in the high 32.  You should cast to `uintptr_t` so the compiler makes sure the upper half is zeroed.  (err, actually you'd have to cast to `unsigned` and *then* to `uintptr_t` to get zero-extension instead of sign-extension.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: The value `i` being passed in is a 32-bit number (int). so it will be a 32-bit register chosen. There may well be garbage in the upper bits.. when you do `incl %0` on the 32-bit destination that should zero the upper 32-bits. On a side note: with a 32-bit target `%q` doesn't promote to a 64-bit register (should stay 32-bit register).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh right, I forgot what the first `incl` was doing :P

Comment: I personally wouldn't have written the code this way, it was about the closest i could think the OP was trying to do if they were looking to use two inc instructions in the template. i wouldn't do it that way. I would have also avoided the `memory` clobber for the preferred alternative but wasn't going to overly complicate the code in a comment lol

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yeah, I also think that's what the OP might have been aiming for, but I didn't take the time to type it up earlier, so +1 on that comment.  Oh BTW, your version needs `asm volatile` in case `i` is unused but `a[1]` *is* used.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Single step the assembly.  Be enlightened.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Care to explain what    incl (%1, %q0, 4) does? I know the parentheses mean memory reference but what are the last two parameters? I've searched far and wide but couldn't find any useful information on q modifier and that kind of syntax (3 operands inside parentheses).

Comment: @Tuhnri : in AT&T syntax means a memory operand. Memory oprands can be displacement(base, index, scale) where the calculation is displacement+base+index*scale. Displacement is a value (in your case there is number outside the parentheses so displacement is 0. That leaves the calculation 0+%1+%q0*4 . %1 is the register for constraint 1. %q0 is constraint 0. The `q` means to tell GCC that the register to use should be the 64-bit version of the register(if building for 32-bit code q picks the 32-bit version of the register)

Comment: So the `incl` instruction i gave would increment the 32-bit memory address pointed to by that memory operand.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Great explanation. Thanks a lot :D